Complex curve integral conversion and residue theorem application
Consider the integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2 r \cos(\theta) + r^2} \,d\theta
\end{align*}
for fixed $0 < r < 1$. Convert this to a complex curve integral around the circle $\mathtt{C}(0; r)$ and use the residue theorem to evaluate the integral and show it has the same value for each $r \in (0, 1)$.
I have started by expressing $r\cos{\theta}$ in terms of $z$ only by substituting $\cos{\theta} = \frac{\left(e^{i \theta }+e^{-i \theta }\right)}{2}$ to get:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2 r \frac{\left(e^{i \theta }+e^{-i \theta }\right)}{2} + r^2} \,d\theta
\end{align*}
Which simplifies to:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1-r^2}{r^2-\left(e^{-i \theta }+e^{i \theta }\right) r+1} \,d\theta
\end{align*}
I want to get the curve integral around $\mathtt{C}(0; r)$ in terms of $z = r e^{i\theta}$ and $\bar{z} = r e^{-i\theta}$ at this stage but am not sure how to form this properly handling the conjugate or how to proceed to calculate the residue from there...?

Let $I$ denote the integral in question. The substitution $z=re^{i\theta}$ is indeed correct, however we do not deal with conjugates. $dz=ir e^{i\theta}d\theta$ and $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$. As $\theta$ varies from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, $z$ varies reverse clockwise in the circle $|z|=r$. By Euler's formula for the cosine, we get $2r\cos\theta=re^{i\theta}+re^{-i\theta}=z+\frac{r^2}{z}$. Putting these all together we get
$$I=\int_{|z|=r}\frac{1-r^2}{1-\left( z+\frac{r^2}{z} \right)+r^2}\frac{dz}{iz}=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{1-r^2}{(1+r^2)z-r^2-z^2}dz.$$
By Cauchy's residue theorem the last integral is $2\pi$ times sum of the residues of the integrand. We see that the integrand has poles at $(1+r^2)z-r^2-z^2=0$ thus $z=1,r^2$. The point $z=1$ is not on the disc $|z|<r$ but $z=r^2$ is since $r^2<r$. Now we calculate the residue as follows,
$$I=2\pi \underset{z=r^2}{\text{Res}}\frac{1-r^2}{(1+r^2)z-r^2-z^2}=2\pi \lim_{z \to r^2} \frac{(1-r^2)(z-r^2)}{(1+r^2)z-r^2-z^2}=2\pi\lim_{z \to r^2}\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2z}=2\pi.$$
This concludes the problem since $I$ is independent of $r$.
